# OwinContext Environment doesn't contains Added element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin, multi-tenant

I am trying to implement multi tenancy in my WebAPI project.

In my Startup.Auth.cs , i am adding selected Tenant object into IOwinContext.

```
       app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            Tenant tenant = GetTenantBasedUrl(ctx.Request.Uri.Host);
            if (tenant == null)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("tenant not found");
            }
            ctx.Environment.Add("MultiTenant", tenant);
            await next();
        }
```

Where GetTenantBaseUrl function is returnnig us the selected Tenant object.
I have made a class implementing ApiController which i would implement to every controller of mine in order to get the Tenant object.

```
public class MultiTenantWebApiController : ApiController
{
    public Tenant Tenant
    {
        get
        {
            object multiTenant;
            IDictionary<string, object> dic =  HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Environment;
            if (!HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Environment.TryGetValue("MultiTenant", out multiTenant))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Could Not Find Tenant");
            }
            return (Tenant)multiTenant; 
        }
    }

}
```

In my controller i am getting "MultiTenant" key from OwinContext Environment but i try to fetch the same from ApplicationOAuthProvider class it doesn't show "MultiTenant" key in my OwinContext Environment ie : getEnvironment variable below:

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly string _publicClientId;

// some code here

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        try
        {
           **IDictionary getEnvironment =  HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Environment;**
      // some code
```

Does anybody know why i am not getting the "MultiTenant" key in OwinContext.Environment of ApplicationOAuthProvider whereas i get it inside my controller ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that you can use the context injected to each of your api controllers so that the tenant and its context is visible across the layers. The context provider can be looking something like this

```
public class ClaimsContextDataProvider : IUserContextDataProvider
    {
        public Guid UserId
        {
            get
            {
                var userId = (Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal)?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid)?.Value;
                return TryGetGuidFromString(userId);
            }
        }
}
```

Then registering the context provider in the DI framework [example of using the Autofac is given below]

`builder.RegisterType<ClaimsContextDataProvider>().As<IUserContextDataProvider>();`

Then have a BaseApiController something like the below snippet

```
public Guid TenantId { get { return _userContext.TenantId; } }

        public BaseApiController(IMapper mapper, IUserContextDataProvider userContext)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
            _userContext = userContext;
        }
```

Accessing the TenantId property of the BaseApiController inside the derived controllers [CountriesController.cs]

```
// POST api/countries
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostCountry(CountryRequestModel requestModel)
        {
            Country country = _mapper.Map<CountryRequestModel, Country>(requestModel);
            country.CreatedOn = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            country.TenantId = TenantId;

            await _countryService.AddAsync(country);

            CountryDto countryDto = _mapper.Map<Country, CountryDto>(country);
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, countryDto);
            response.Headers.Location = GetCountryLink(country.Id);

            return response;
        }
```

You can take a look at the sample app and the template given in the below link

[Multi-Tenant dev template](https://github.com/d-saravanan/multitenant.dev.template/blob/master/samples/GenericRepository.EntityFramework.SampleWebApi/App_Start/DependencyRegistryConfig.cs)

Its a little bit deep to explain here, please feel free to read the docs [here](https://d-saravanan.github.io/multitenant.dev.template/)

Comment: Awesome Saravanan.. Thanks for providing detail docs for the same. Appreciate it !

Comment: @TarunOhri: If you find it useful, please do mark it as an answer